# How to get the changed Object in ember observer

Tags: ember.js

I want to get the changed Object in Ember observer in view,

```
watchStatus: ( ->
    console.log "I want the changed Object here???"
    map = @get('map')
    trucks = @get('controller.model.content')
    i = 0
    while i < trucks.length
      @makeMarker trucks[i], map
    i++
).observes('controller.model.content.@each.status')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array observer then.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_addArrayObserver

Answer (score 0):

The callback function in ember observer is called with parameters. The first parameter has the current context ( i.e., the component/controller ) object and the second param is the key which fired the change.

```
watchPerson:Ember.observer("person.firstName,person.lastName", function(context, key){
         //so here the key is your boy
})
```

or some people may use the other way

```
watchPerson: function(context, key){
             //so here the key is your boy
}.observes("person.firstName","person.lastName")
```